# Node.JS application on AppFog responding with 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: node.js, express, appfog

I'm developing a Node.JS app. When running on localhost everything works fine.

After I've deployed it to AppFog, I randomly get 503 Service Unavailable responses either for static resources (served using express.static() middleware, Express is version 3.1.0), or API calls (serving JSON documents from MongoDB). Also in AppFog console I see reported status 0%. Application logs show nothing. And it seems the applications does not stop.

I tried running single instance with 2GB of memory as well as 16 instances each with 128MB still getting 503.

Application is deployed to US East infra. It uses MongoHQ add-on.

Have you experienced this behavior on AppFog or with your Node.JS apps? Thanks for any help.

Comment: You need to contact support , directly , and remember , APPFOG still is a beta service.

Comment: @mpm I also wrote to AppFog Google Group. AppFog's support suggested to restart the app. It did not help. So I wanted to know if anyone else has experienced this.

Comment: hi @JakubKulhan! i've deployed a rails app on appfog and i have the same 503 errors like you, especially with https.

Comment: @mathieurip Seems like problem with AppFog's HTTPS. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/appfog-users/qg8evGWtLnw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bug with HTTPS in AppFog confirmed in their Google Group.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick tip: you can use the command `af logs <appname>` to view your application logs.

Comment: No one had suggested this, plus I posted a similar response to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13844376/on-appfog-how-to-find-the-reason-for-500-internal-server-error, as it didn't seem to be a well-known CLI option at the time. Want help in future? Drop the attitude.